# Is a certificate considered self-signed if the Certificate Authority used to create it is self-signed?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

The certificate's subject name and issuer name are different but the certificate authority used to create the certificate has the same issuer and name.

Therefore since the certificate authority is self-signed, are the certificates it creates also considered self-signed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Self-issued means that the Issuer and Subject are the same and self-signed means a self-issued certificate whose contained public key can verify its own signature.  (Some software and most humans ignore the signature check and just treat all self-issued as self-signed.)

Note that all root authorities are self-signed, because the PKI trust system has to start somewhere.